# Laravel 5 Query Builder Recordset Array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel-5

I have created a query with query builder that returns multiple rows and when I try to print the records using foreach loop, getting this error:

"Trying to get property of non-object"

```
Controller:
$productPhotos = DB::table('productsphotos')->where('ProductId', $id);

View:
@foreach ($productPhotos as $item)
  <li><img src="{{ $item->PhotoThumb }}" /></li>
@endforeach
```

Comment: do var_dump on $productPhotos and see if it's an object or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

```
$productPhotos = DB::table('productsphotos')->where('ProductId', $id);
```

to

```
 $productPhotos = DB::table('productsphotos')->where('ProductId', $id)->get();
```

Comment: I have created a join query as:
$product = DB::table('products')->join('currencies', 'products.CurrencyId', '=', 'currencies.Id')->where('products.Id', $id)->first();

Both the 'products' and 'currencies' tables contain 'Name' column. I want to print both separately in view. How can I do this ?

Comment: Try This:
`$product = DB::table('products')
  ->select('products.name as products_name')
  ->join('currencies', 'products.CurrencyId', '=', 'currencies.Id')
  ->where('products.Id', $id)
  ->first();`

Answer (score 0):

```
$productPhotos = DB::table('productsphotos')->where('ProductId', $id)->get();
```

This query will give you the object array where as if you want array you can use

```
$productPhotos = DB::table('productsphotos')->where('ProductId', $id)->get()->toArray();
```